# Pandas add values of row if index match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different amount of rows for simplicity I will use an example.

DF1

```
       1   2   3
AA_ABC 1.0 1.0 1.0
AA_ABC NaN NaN NaN
AB_ABC 1.0 1.0 1.0
AC_ABC 1.0 1.0 1.0
AC_ABC NaN NaN NaN
AC_ABC NaN NaN NaN
 ....  ... ... ...
```

DF2

```
       1   2    3
AA_ABC .13 0.0  -.3
AB_ABC .24 0.0  .4
AC_ABC 0.0 -.07 .02
AD_ABC 0.0 0.0  0.0
 ....  ... ...  ...
```

What I would like to do is search DF1 and DF2 for index match if there is a match I'd like to add the entire row of DF2 to DF1 but skip when a row in DF1 has NaN values as there can be duplicates in DF1 that don't have values attached to them, that I do need to keep in place for the final result.

Desired result

```
       1    2    3
AA_ABC 1.13 1.0  0.7
AA_ABC NaN  NaN  NaN
AB_ABC 1.24 1.0  1.4
AC_ABC 1.0  .93  1.02
AC_ABC NaN  NaN  NaN
AC_ABC NaN  NaN  NaN
 ....  ... ... ...
```

EDIT: DF1 has non unique index IDs which I would need to keep in place, therefore groupby is also something I can not perse perform.

EDIT: I further experimented a bit by trying to get a total index and then adding the dataframes on the combined index

```
final_index = np.concatenate([df1.index, df2.index])
temp_result = (df1.reindex(final_index)+ df2.reindex(final_index))
```

but receive a value error ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

EDIT: Maybe iteration is the key still trying to solve it

Comment: `df1.loc[df2.index] = df2`?

Comment: there I receive that 5 index values are missing, maybe for clarification, the index of DF2 is not the same length as DF1. Row count is not the same in DF2 and DF1.

Comment: sure, given the example you've shown, the indices of df1 nonnull rows are exactly the indices of df2 rows (btw I made a typo in last comment: I meant += instead of =)

Comment: `temp_df1.loc[temp_df2.index] += temp_df2` gets me this keyerror.

   5842     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   5844 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
-> 5845 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "['PR_MST001', 'PR_MST002', 'PR_MST003', 'PR_MST004', 'PR_MST005', 'PR_MST006'] not in index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started by making code to reproduce your `dataframe`

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(''',1,2,3
AA_ABC,1.0,1.0,1.0
AA_ABC,NaN,NaN,NaN
AB_ABC,1.0,1.0,1.0
AC_ABC,1.0,1.0,1.0
AC_ABC,NaN,NaN,NaN
AC_ABC,NaN,NaN,NaN'''), sep=',', index_col=0)
```

and

```
df_2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(''',1,2,3
AA_ABC,.13,0.0,-.3
AB_ABC,.24,0.0,.4
AC_ABC,0.0,-.07,.02
AD_ABC,0.0,0.0,0.0'''), sep=',', index_col=0)
```

Then I merge them into a single `dataframe`

```
df = df_1.merge(df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Which gives:

```
        1_x 2_x 3_x 1_y     2_y      3_y
AA_ABC  1.0 1.0 1.0 0.13    0.00    -0.30
AA_ABC  NaN NaN NaN 0.13    0.00    -0.30
AB_ABC  1.0 1.0 1.0 0.24    0.00    0.40
AC_ABC  1.0 1.0 1.0 0.00    -0.07   0.02
AC_ABC  NaN NaN NaN 0.00    -0.07   0.02
AC_ABC  NaN NaN NaN 0.00    -0.07   0.02
```

Then I sum the columns, and I selected the expected columns

```
df['1'] = df['1_x'] + df['1_y']
df['2'] = df['2_x'] + df['2_y']
df['3'] = df['3_x'] + df['3_y']
df[['1', '2', '3']]
```

And here is the result

```
           1    2   3
AA_ABC  1.13 1.00   0.70
AA_ABC  NaN   NaN   NaN
AB_ABC  1.24  1.00  1.40
AC_ABC  1.00  0.93  1.02
AC_ABC  NaN   NaN   NaN
AC_ABC  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

As you can note, I didn't ignore the rows with `NaN`, I juste include them because `NaN` plus something is also `Nan`